# how to change hebrew path into english in dropbox api(Java)

Tags: java, api, dropbox, dropbox-api, hebrew

I'm working with the dropbox api to java and i have trying to read from dropbox.

When I use the path of the api it looks like this -

```
טיול פסח path: /Public/טיול פסח
```

(Ignore the hebrew words it's like - 
someFolderName paht: /Public/someFolderName)

and it's looks as usual, but when I try to go to this path it's give me  this exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at node.Main.listFolders(Main.java:102)
    at node.Main.main(Main.java:112)
```

When I use the toString() method of the api that give some of the metaData including the path of the folder it's shows me this -

```
טיול פסח toString(): Folder("/Public/\u05d8\u05d9\u05d5\u05dc \u05e4\u05e1\u05d7"...)
```

When the string within the quotes should be the path.
When I tried to enter this as the path it's give me this exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at node.Main.listFolders(Main.java:102)
    at node.Main.main(Main.java:112)
```

The code example:

The path is **"/Public"** and it's the argument s.
client is the access to my dropbox.
listing is list of children of the root folder.

```
public static void listFolders(String s) throws DbxException, IOException {
        //list of children. 
        DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren(s);

        for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
            System.out.println("    " + child.name + " toString(): " + child.toString());
            System.out.println("    " + child.name + " path: " + child.path);
        }

    }
```

The output of this with **"/Public"** as argument is:

```
טיול פסח toString(): Folder("/Public/\u05d8\u05d9\u05d5\u05dc \u05e4\u05e1\u05d7", iconName="folder", mightHaveThumbnail=false)
טיול פסח path: /Public/
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I edit it with some code..

Comment: If it actually expects '\uNNNN` within the path then you could try doubling the backslashes (to represent the string `\uABCD` in a Java string literal you'd need `"\\uABCD"`)

Comment: What do you mean with "Enter it as path"? how do you enter it?

Comment: Agreed with @Dawnkeeper. You said "when I try to go to this path" and "when I tried to enter this as the path" but you never said what you're actually doing. Are you talking about code you wrote? If so, where's the code that tries to use that path?